# play mp3 and mp3+g mediaplayer for php website

Tags: php, flash, mp3, media-player

I want to develope one php application , in which i want to run mp3 , mp4 and mp3+g files. 
I have use flowplayer for audio and video file .but flowplayer unable to run mp3+g file . 
plz help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Audio APIs. Not all browsers support MP3 though. Here is a link for you for details. [W3School HTML5 Audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp)